# How to assign array values one by one to setTimeout in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to insert array values after  `setTimeout()` executes. At the beginning default value must be `setTimeout(msg, 60000)` after that, I want to insert arr values one by one after execution.

For example:

This is my Array `arr=[2, 5, 8]` at the beginning `setTimeout(msg, 60000)` after execution `setTimeout(msg, arr[0])` after second execution `setTimeout(msg, arr[1])` so on I need to add arr elements to the function. Please can I know solution for this problem?

Comment: **Don't scream!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a recursive timer:

```
  const times = [2, 5, 8];

  function next() {
    msg();
    if(times.length) setTimeout(next, times.shift() * 1000);
  }

 setTimeout(next, 6000);
```

Comment: I was thinking he was wanting something like that, but this bit `after that i want to insert arr valuse one by one after execution.`  got me confused...

Comment: @keith I guess  he wants to insert `arr[0]` into `setTimeout` and so on, thats how I understood it

Comment: add the code to the question @sd_dewasurendra. it will make it easier for others to find a specific or generic solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: @sd_dewasurendra no worries :)

Comment: @rai no! answers go into the answer section!

Comment: @JonasWilms can you please tell me if I want to subtract some value from each array element when executing the function and do the same thing, how can I perform that thank you